# DbSet<T>.Attach() method does't mark modified properties as "modified"?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

let's say we have a Person class(with properties of Id and Age), let's say we need to change the Age of a person whose id is 1 from 29 to 30,

```
Person p = new Person(){ Id = 1 }  //Age is default to 0 here, but does't matter, because it is going to be changed later
var entity = context.Persons.Attach(p);
p.Age = 30;

Console.WriteLine("entity state:" + entity.State);
foreach (var modifiedProperty in entity.Properties.Where(p => p.IsModified))
{
   Console.Write($"The {modifiedProperty.Metadata.Name} property is marked as modified");
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

and the output shows:

the `entity.State` is **unchanged** and **no properties are marked as modified**, but still EF core generated an Update SQL to set [Age] = 30, I'm confused, if the entity state is unchanged and EF core think there is no property modifications, then EF core shouldn't generate an Update SQL?

and if I use Update() method instead of Attach()

```
...
var entity = context.Persons.Update(p);
...
```

then everything is normal, the Entity status is modified, Age is identified as modified property?

Comment: myContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

Comment: @JohnB I updated my post.  so why use Update() method can identify modified properties while Attach() cannot?

Answer (score 1):

The states of entities will not be updated immediately but recalculated when `context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()` is called.

The property `context.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled` is set to true by default. It means when `context.SaveChanges()` is called, `context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()` will be called first automatically, and then the states of entities are updated.

According to the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.update?view=efcore-2.1 , all properties of the entity object will be marked in `Modified` state by the update method itself, no matter whether the property value is really modified. So the `Update` method is not using detecting change feature of EF, but set the sate of entity forcibly.

Comment: so why if I use Attach() method, EF cannot identify modified properties but if I use Update() method then EF can identify modified properties?